# Robot Framework api test with Oauth2 - pass generated token to other test cases

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, robotframework

Using similar code to this one, I am able to successfully generate a Token and authorize the request bellow it. Both actions happen in one test case. I tried creating a new test case with only copying the second request code and of course it says unauthorized.
So my question is, since I can generate a token in the first test case, what do I have to add in order to use/pass the already generated token for a second, third, fourth, test cases?

````
${data}=     Create Dictionary    Token_Name=TestTokenname    grant_type=<grant type>    client_Id=<your Id>     Client_Secret=<Your client secret>    scope=<your scpe>
${headers}=   Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

${resp}=    RequestsLibrary.Post Request    OA2    identity/connect/token    data=${data}    headers=${headers}
BuiltIn.Log To Console    ${resp}
BuiltIn.Log To Console    ${resp.status_code}
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
Dictionary Should Contain Value    ${resp.json()}   Testtokenname
${accessToken}=    evaluate    $resp.json().get("access_token")
BuiltIn.Log to Console    ${accessToken}
${token}=    catenate    Bearer    ${accessToken}
BuiltIn.Log to Console    ${token}
${headers1}=  Create Dictionary    Authorization=${token} 

RequestsLibrary.Create Session    GT    <Your Server URL>    verify=${True}        
${resp}=  RequestsLibrary.Get Request  GT    <Your API URL>    headers=${headers1}
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200 ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, after getting and storing token in a variable, add the below line of code immediately. Variables set with this keyword are globally available in all subsequent test suites, test cases and user keywords.

```
Set Global Variable    ${token}
```

More detailed explanation in the below link
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable

Comment: Thank you Manish, 
if this is the case, then in the requests that I am going to add in the separate test cases, 
where should the global variable ${token}, be defined?

Comment: You can add the line of code "Set Global Variable    ${token}" after "${token}=    catenate    Bearer    ${accessToken}" this line in your code. Once you added, you can use in any test case.

${token} variable will have your token value until the script execution ends. So you no need to do change after. You need to use the variable ${token} wherever you need it